# prevent right click on href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a href="Profile.aspx?ProfileId=1" class="view-profile">View profile<a>
```

When the user click on my href there is an treatment=" .ajax script that will allow or  the user to view the profile."

the problem is when that when the user right click my href,the treatment is ignored and the user can see the all profiles.

How can I prevent the right click?
Or how can I execute the same treatment(check) when the user right click my href.
I have tested the below code but not working:

```
    $(function() {
            $('.view-profile').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
             return false;
              });
     });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about proper permission checking before displaying profiles?

Comment: You should also know that contextmenu is not a standard event, some browsers (e.g. Opera, Konqueror) don't support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on client-side validation to control user privileges, because it can be easily hacked; rather, use both server-side and client-side validation or simply server-side alone.

Comment: Thanks minitech .the validation actually is done via  a websrvice via .ajax.the problem is with right click.

Comment: The thing is, if the user can simply go to a URL and view all user profiles, you *also* need to implement that validation on the page that displays the profiles. Ajax validation is still client-side, you always need to validate an action when it is performed.

Comment: oki i will add the server validation before opening the href page.but i don't even want to open it via right click.

Comment: the problem with if if i do server check,the user will be allow to open the page and again will be redirected to the same page if not allowed to see the profile,calling the same method many times!!

Comment: It's not good UI design to have an unclickable link - you might frustrate people. Simply remove the link so it cannot be clicked in the first place.

Comment: @user I think you have a fundamentally broken app design.

Comment: oki,the problem is that the href is rendered via jquery.why that @deceze,should not use .ajax to check privileges?

Comment: Okay, so instead of removing the link, don't add it in the first place with jQuery.

Comment: i use jquery because there is not just one href,a list of hrefs(table of profiles),among them the user can see some and other no.

Comment: @user If the user does not have permission to see a certain URL, the link should not show up for her in the first place. If the user guesses the URL and tries to access it directly anyway, the server needs to deny that to the user with a proper error message. It should not break with an endless redirect. Having the client make the ultimate decision about whether to show the contents of a target URL to the user is a farce.

Comment: Exactly. "i use jquery because there is not just one href,a list of hrefs(table of profiles),among them the user can see some and other no." Well then selectively add the links! It doesn't matter if you're using jQuery or not, jQuery does not prevent friendly UIs and secure design.

Comment: i show those that the user can't see to incentivize him to ask for seeing them :) .yes the solution is to add the server side check in the href destination page.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script language=JavaScript>
<!--

//Disable right mouse click Script
//By Maximus (maximus@nsimail.com) w/ mods by DynamicDrive
//For full source code, visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com

var message="Function Disabled!";

///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")

// --> 
</script>
```

--source: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright.htm

Comment: This is terribly unfriendly to users and debuggers alike, and is downright annoying in every situation.

Comment: @minitech your talking about a personal preference.

Comment: No, I'm not. It is strongly discouraged in every book I've read, every site I've seen, and I know many people who are frustrated because they want to copy link URLs but can't. This script will disable a right-click on any link in the page, preventing people from opening it in a new tab or window, sharing it with others, etc. and it doesn't even stop it when people drag the link to the Desktop or into the navigation bar.

Comment: Wow, that script is sooo 1996 - where did you dig that up from? Don't tell me - you Googled for it. Browser sniffing (by any method other than the rare use of conditional comments for IE) went out of fashion late last millenium, as can be seen by the inferred browser names. When was the last time you came across someone using IE 4 or Navigator 4?

Comment: Not to mention this can be easily defeated with any number of plugins, the View Source menu item, or simply by turning off javascript.